# AngularJS Pre-served $params variables for a controller defined inside of a route

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to pass your own variables in a defined route in AngularJS?

The reason why I'm doing this is because I have to data representations of the same page (one is a filtered view in terms of the JSON data) and all I need to do is give a boolean flag to the $params array to let the controller function know that this page is either filtered or non-filtered.

Something like this:

```
var Ctrl = function($scope, $params) {
  if($params.filtered) {
    //make sure that the ID is there and use a different URL for the JSON data
  }
  else {
    //use the URL for JSON data that fetches all the data
  }
};

Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];

angular.modlule('App', []).config(['$routeProvider', function($routes) {

  $routes.when('/full/page',{
    templateURL : 'page.html',
    controller : Ctrl
  });

  $routes.when('/full/page/with/:id',{
    templateURL : 'page.html',
    controller : Ctrl,
    params : {
      filtered : true
    }
  });

}]);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [`$routeProvider` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider), the `route` parameter of `$routeProvider.when()` has property `resolve`:

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

Something like this should work:

```
function Ctrl($scope, isFiltered) {
  if(isFiltered) {
    //make sure that the ID is there and use a different URL for the JSON data
  }
  else {
    //use the URL for JSON data that fetches all the data
  }
}
Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'isFiltered'];

angular.modlule('App', []).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/full/page',{
    templateURL: 'page.html',
    controller: Ctrl
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/full/page/with/:id',{
    templateURL: 'page.html',
    controller: Ctrl,
    resolve: {
      isFiltered: function() { return true; }
    }
  });

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not currently possible to specify additional parameters for a route. Having said this your use case could be easily covered by testing if :id is defined as part of [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeParams).

The thing is that AngularJS will match your routes either on '/full/page' or '/full/page/with/:id' so just by testing $routeParams for id presence in your controller:

`if ($routeParams.id)`

you would know in which case your are.

The alternative is to use different controllers for different routes.

Comment: Yeah I though of that. The only problem is that if the ID is undefined (and the URL is malformed) then it will delegate to the other URL.

Comment: So the way that I solved this was by creating another controller function and then adding the URL into the $params object and then having the primary controller check for a missing URL and then add then if its missing then setup the other URL as that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get sneak params directly through `$route.current.$$route`.

```
function Ctrl($scope, $route) {
  var filtered = $route.current.$$route.params.filtered;
}

angular.modlule('App', []).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/full/page/with/:id',{
    templateURL: 'page.html',
    controller: Ctrl,
    params : {
      filtered : true
    }
  });

}]);
```

Although it work, I'd still prefer a `resolve` solution. `params` (or any name of your choice) could be overwritten by angularjs in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

mething like this must be work for filter:

```
function caseFilterCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('./data/myDatas.json').success( function(data){
                                        var arr = new Array();
                                        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                                            if(data[i].filter == $routeParams.id){
                                                arr.push(data[i]);                              }
                                            }
                                        $scope.filtered= arr;
                                        });
    }

 caseFilterCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http']; //for minified bug issue
```

and the routage :

```
angular.module('myFilterApp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){ 
                $routeProvider.when('/filter/:id', {templateUrl: './view/partial/filter.html', controller: caseFilterCtrl});
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/filter/01'});
            }
            ]);
```